# Medida para Sumar Valores entre Rangos de Fechas Power BI

Tags: powerbi, microsoft

Buen día.

Actualmente estoy buscando la manera de que exista una columna que acumule (sume) los valores desde el inicio del año en curso (2019-01-01) hasta el mes que está seleccionado.

[image: img01]

La columna "Valor" acumula el contenido de "valorHoras", una columna en el modelo. El acumulado lo hace por cada usuario de cada área, en un mes determinado. La columna "Valor YTD" debería acumular el contenido de "valorHoras" de manera tal que cada usuario tenga el acumulado de todo el año, por ejemplo para el usuario "S3 XXX" debe acumularse el valor de "valorHoras" desde que comienza el año (2019-01-01) hasta la fecha de hoy (2019-12-13). Sin embargo no es eso lo que está haciendo, actualmente está acumulando algunos de los valores.

Luego la medida para "Valor YTD" es la siguiente:

```
TotalValorYTD = TOTALYTD
(
    SUM('Grafica-HorasReportadas'[valorHoras]),
    'Filtro-Periodo'[fecha],
    ALL('Filtro-Periodo')
)
```

Las tablas "Grafica-HorasReportadas" y "Filtro-Periodo" tienen la siguiente relación.

[image: img02]

En "Filtro-Periodo" están todos los días de todos los meses de los años desde 2003 hasta 2019.

Luego existen tres filtros de fechas que parten de la data de "Filtro-Periodo", más específicamente "Mes / Año" selecciona un mes en concreto.

[image: img03]

¿Cómo pudiera ser para que "Valor YTD" siempre muestre el acumulado desde Enero para el mes y año seleccionados? Ejemplo: si se selecciona "Mayo, 2017", entonces "Valor YTD" acumulará todo lo de "valorHoras" de ese usuario desde el 01/01/2017 hasta el 30/05/2017.

Saludos y gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que la medida que buscas es la que expones, aunque simplificada.

```
TotalValorYTD = TOTALYTD
(
    SUM('Grafica-HorasReportadas'[valorHoras]),
    'Filtro-Periodo'[fecha]
)
```

De esta forma la medida será sensible a lo que pongas en el informe: usuario, año, mes, etc.